# There is already an active transaction

Tags: php, pdo

i have a code that use commit and rollback

```
$pdo = new dbpdo();
    $fields = ['id','last','first'];
    $values = [NULL,'asd','asd'];
    //$pdo->db->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $pdo->db->beginTransaction();
        //echo 'connected';
        //$pdo->InsertBatch('staff',implode(',',$data));
        //$pdo->InsertBatch('staff',implode(',',$fields), implode(',',$values));
        $pdo->InsertBatch('staff',$fields, $values);
        //$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO staff('id','first','last') VALUES ('NULL','asd','asd')");
        //$pdo->execute();
        $pdo->commit();
        //$message = 'success';
        echo 'Save';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //die("Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage());
        $pdo->rollBack();
        //$message = 'sayop';
        //die("Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage());
        echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

my question is . when i execute this . . is says. There is already an active transaction and data is has not save in database. . dbpdo class has extend PDO class.

Comment: Looks like `$pdo->InsertBatch` method tries to create new transaction

Comment: In my Case, On upper Scope (before calling function where error occurred)
variable $stmt was running, i add Line "$stmt = null;"

Answer (score 5):

I got the same scenario here today... I was trying to insert some master-detail records at Firebird and getting *There is already an active transaction* error.

My solution was to enable and disable the autocommit option, try this:

`$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, 0)`

before calling `$pdo->db->beginTransaction()`

And when you complete your transaction, re-enable autocommit:

`$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, 1)`

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.begintransaction.php#113602

Answer (score 1):

At some point you are opening the connection and it is not closing.
Ex.:

```
function insert($object){
        try {                
            $this->_DB->beginTransaction(); // OPEN TRANSATION
            $query  = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES (?,?,?,?)';
            $stmt   = $this->_DB->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute( [$object->id, $object->name, $object->last_name, $object->email] );
            $this->_DB->commit(); //CLOSE -> In some function it must be missing!
            return $stmt->rowCount();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_DB->rollBack();
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
}
```